# Função lambda para retornar maior valor de uma lista de dicionários

Tags: python, expressões-lambda, dicionário

Boa noite. Alguém poderia me explicar como a função lambda abaixo funciona? Não estou entendendo o por que dela retornar o maior valor no dicionário. Outra coisa que eu gostaria de saber, o 'x' está representando a cada dicionário dentro da lista e não a lista em si, saberiam me dizer o porque? Obrigado.

```
dic = [
    {"name": "bread", "price": 100},
    {"name": "wine", "price": 138},
    {"name": "meat", "price": 15},
    {"name": "water", "price": 1}
]    
sorted(dic, key = lambda x: -x['price'])[:2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Como o `lambda` funciona:

Lambda é uma definição de função em tempo real, mas funciona como uma função normal.

```py
lamda_soma_um = lambda x: x + 1

def func_soma_um(x):
    return x + 1

lambda_soma_um(5) == func_soma_um(5)
```

No seu caso, a função lambda está recebendo um dicionário e retornando o valor da chave `price` negativo (tem um `-` (sinal de menos) antes do `x['price']`).

Ou seja, se a função lambda definida for aplicada a cada linha da sua lista os retornos seriam respectivamente -100, -138, -15 e -1.

A partir deste ponto, acretido que a duvida seja em relação a função `sorted`. Quando um `callable` é passado como paramentro no kw `key`, a função sorted vai passar cada item da sua lista para o `callable` e vai usar o retorno para ordenar em ordem crescente.

Considerando o retorno de cada item da sua lista e ordenando-os de forma crescente, teremos -138, -100, -15, -1.

```py
>>> sorted(dic, key = lambda x: -x['price'])
[{'name': 'wine', 'price': 138}, {'name': 'bread', 'price': 100}, {'name': 'meat', 'price': 15}, {'name': 'water', 'price': 1}]
```

Quando voce adiciona `[:2]` você está pegando os primeiros 2 itens da lista.